# How to store setting credentials in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a school management project and I want to add a setting panel in my project, but unable to determine how to store the settings for a project in java?
how can i make it possible?

Comment: post what you have so far and we'll point you in the write direction. this isn't a free code writing service, no one is going to write any code for you

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be with the [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API. You can save and load things without worrying how they're stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many different things to store persistent data. Persistent means data will be stored after your app stopped running.

1. **XML file:**
   [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)
2. A **database** like: [JAVA SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/getstart/index.html)
3. **JSON file**: [JSON API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)
4. **Java Properties**: [Properties Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

---

However I recommend you JAXB, because I think it is the easiest way.